# Set JSON input for the @timestamp field in Kibana visualizations

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

The problem is that the timezone for the visualizations are default to UTC as es default timestamp is UTC.
Now if I want to have an accurate visualization, I need to tell Kibana to interpret the timestamp in es records as my local time zone say it's America/Los_Angeles.

Is there any way to add time_zone to below JSON box?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add this in the JSON input text area

```
{"time_zone": "America/Los_Angeles"}
```

Basically, any `date_histogram` parameter that is not configurable through the UI can go in there.